# Methods of addressing someone in email

Tags: professionalism, email

I recently sent an email to apply to a job. The only contact listed didn't have any title - let's say this is Jane Doe. In my email, I greeted with "Hello Ms. Doe"; in the response, the email was ended with "Thank you, Jane".

In further correspondences, should I address them with the same one I opened with or is it correct to address it to the name used by the receiver?

For example, should I use "Hello Ms. Doe" or "Hello Jane"?

**Edit:** It should be noted that the initial response I had received began with "Daimyo", and I closed my initial email with "Thank you, Daimyo Kirby"

---

I'm aware of this [similar question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11079/26694) but my question isn't about whether I should use a greeting or not but rather about if it's okay to use the name/title used by the receiver even if that name/title is informal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest sticking with "Ms. Doe" for now, with perhaps a postscript on the next note saying "Would you rather I address you as Ms. Doe, or as Jane? I don't want to presume, but since you signed your last note informally I thought you might prefer a more conversational tone."

That avoids any risk of misunderstanding.